# Type `UnityEngine.UI.Text' does not contain a definition for `Text'

Tags: c#, unity

I came from Unreal Engine 4. I created a script, and I keep getting an error:

> Assets/scripts/UpgradeManager.cs(17,18): error CS1061: Type
>   `UnityEngine.UI.Text' does not contain a definition for `Text' and
>   no extension method `Text' of type `UnityEngine.UI.Text' could be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

My code is:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;


public class UpgradeManager : MonoBehaviour {

    public Click click;
    public UnityEngine.UI.Text iteminfo;
    public float cost;
    public int count = 0;
    public int clickpower;
    public string itemName;
    public float _newCost;

    void Update()
    {
        iteminfo.Text = itemName + "/nCost: " + cost + "/nPower: +" + clickpower;
    }

    public void PurchaseUpgrade()
    {
        if (click.money >= cost) 
        {
            click.money -= cost;
            count += 1;
            click.moneyperclick += clickpower;
            cost = Mathf.Round(cost * 1.15f);
            _newCost = Mathf.Pow(cost, _newCost = cost);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: For future use of this site, remember: **1.** Read your error messages and follow up on what they tell you - in this case, a visit to the docs would have shown you that there is indeed no **T**ext property here, and that the correct spelling is **t**ext, all lowercase. **2.** "I need help with my game" describes EVERY post on this site, so it's never useful as a title. Always make your title descriptive of what your actual problem is, so people who know how to solve it, or others with the same problem, can find it. **3.** Use the post preview to ensure your code is formatted correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Identifiers in C# are case sensitive. You want `iteminfo.text` not `iteminfo.Text`

You can [verify in the docs that the UnityEngine.UI.Text.text property](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.2/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Text-text.html) is all-lowercase.